# Setup metrics for LTD Viper 50 electric guitar

Tags: electric-guitar, setup

I want to setup my viper 50 electric guitar but I cant find the setup metrics for this model.
Can someone know the setup metrics for this model?

Answer (score 2):

The ESP manual for guitars and basses includes setup guidelines. You can download it here (PDF download):

http://www.americanmusical.com/ItemFiles/Manual/ESPElectricGuitarManual.pdf

Here are setup specs I was able to find in the manual:

- Recommended neck relief: .3 - .5 mm
- Factory action (height at 12th fret): 2.0 mm bass side, 1.5 mm treble side
- Factory pickup height (distance from bottom of string): 2.5 mm bass side, 1.5 mm treble side
- Factory string gauges: 46/36/26/17/13/10